# ST_Within and ST_Contains not working for Latitude and Longitude in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, geolocation

I have a table "tbl_location" in PostGIS which has latitude and longitude, so I created a new column called "point_location" :

```
update "tbl_location"  set point_location = 
ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326), 26913);
```

I have another table which is available [here](http://bniajfi.org/vital_signs/data_downloads/) has MultiPolygon field and I am trying to find in which polygon a location(lat/lng) belongs. For that, I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT a.id, b.csa2010
FROM baltimore."vs14_housing" b, baltimore."tbl_location" a 
WHERE 
ST_Intersects(a.point_location,  b.geom) 
    or 
ST_Contains(a.point_location, b.geom)
    or
ST_Within(a.point_location, b.geom)
```

It is not returning any records. Data type for geom column in vs14_housing is geometry (MultiPolygon). Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: take out the all the quotes in both queries

Comment: don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39778742/327026)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the correct spatial reference ID? The vs14_housing data you referenced is [102685](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102685/).

If you use your query using the UTM([26913](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26913/)), no results.

But if you change it to 102685, it works.  Unless you projected your vs14_housing data (which you failed to mention in the question).

```
with cte as 
(
    select 1 as id, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-76.6129, 39.3106), 4326), 102685) point_location
    ,st_astext(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-76.6129, 39.3106), 4326), 102685)) wkt 
)
SELECT a.id, b.csa2010
FROM public."vs14_housing" b, cte a 
WHERE 
ST_Intersects(a.point_location,  b.geom) 
    or 
ST_Contains(a.point_location, b.geom)
    or
ST_Within(a.point_location, b.geom)
```

[image]